# Function which will delete part of string

Tags: c, string, substring

I need to create a function which will delete part of string. I can use stdio.h and stdlib.h only.

E.g.: I have this string: "`Dad and mom /* and sister */ are at home`". And I need to delete the part which begin with `/*` and ends with `*/`. So the result will be "`Dad and mom are at home`".

Comment: In your example there is no `*/` ending text.

Comment: @tadman: markdown ate the star.

Comment: Does it have only one pair of `/*` and `*/` as it simplify code?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strstr` (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strstr.htm) to find start delimiter and again to find end delimiter.

Then you could use `memmove` (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memmove/) to move the remaining part of the string.

If you can have multiple part to remove, then you can do that in a loop.

Try to do it on paper first and also try to debug your program to see if it does what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 0):

C doesn't really have 'strings' as a type you can do things with.  Instead, C "strings" are a concept -- a sequence of characters in memory, terminated by a NUL character.  As a result, to do anything with strings you need to understand memory management.

Generally, beginning programmers (and examples) do things with fixed-sized arrays and mixture of static (constant) strings and strings in fixed-size arrays that are assumed to fit (which you should always check).

So in your case, you just say you "have a string" -- but don't say how or where you "have" it.  If you have it in a memory buffer that is big enough to hold it, then you could modify the buffer in place to contain the (shorter) desired string.  Or you could copy it to another buffer that is large enough to hold the modified string.  Those would be two very different C functions both of which could be described as "deleting part of a string"

Answer (score 0):

`str` has to be modifiable

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


char *RemoveComment(char *str)
{
    char *start;
    char *end;


    do
    {
        start = strstr(str, "/*");
        end = strstr(str, "*/");
        if(start && end && end > start)
        {
            memmove(start, end + 2, strlen(end + 2) + 1);
        }
    }while (start && end);
    return str;
}


int main()
{

    char text[] = "D/*ad a*/nd mom /* and sister */ ar/*e at*/ ho/*me*/";
    printf("%s\n", RemoveComment(text));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, as it seems to be an homework, you are not really helping OP to learn by giving complete code.